# How to configure @Transactional support to Redis in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

I am currently working on a project which is using Redis mainly for caching purposes, I am using Oracle as the main database and Spring Data JPA to handle the database layer in my project. I need to know how to use @Transactional annotation support to handle transactions in Redis. I have already referred to lots of tutorials and documentation regarding this scenario. In most of those tutorials, there is always the same set of source codes available. But still, I didn't have a clear idea about the implementation. Because in my application there is already a data source available which I configured through property file. (Oracle database) So I doubt the implementation of the dataSource bean. And I couldn't understand the usage of transactionManager bean too. How should I implement this properly please give a detailed explanation.

Source code which I found on the internet.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement // 1
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        // Configure redisTemplate
        StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
        stringRedisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        / / Open transaction support
        stringRedisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true); // 2
        return stringRedisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource()); // 3
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Updated :
Currently configured datasource properties in apppication.properties file.

```
# OracleDB connection settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.20.108:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# HikariCP settings
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=redis-sample-pool
```

[Resource about the Redis Transactions handling](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#:%7E:text=MULTI%2C%20EXEC%2C%20DISCARD%20and%20WATCH,are%20serialized%20and%20executed%20sequentially..)

Comment: This is all you need to do.. Are you seeing any issue with  this code?

Comment: @sonus21 The problem is I don't have any clear idea about the implementation of dataSource bean. As I mentioned this is a code which I got from the internet. This is not my code. Here you can see dataSource bean implementation is empty. What should I implement inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

There're two ways to configure DataSource

- Using the config file

  ```
  spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost
  spring.datasource.username=test
  spring.datasource.password=test1234
  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  #hibernate config dialect for JPA, choose dialect based on the db version
  spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  ```

You can create manually the same by reading these properties, with the help of DataSourceBuilder

```
@Bean
public  DataSource dataSource(){
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("test");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("test1234");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: @Sonous21 I have already configured those properties in my application.properties file.Please see the updated section of my original post.I am asking here is how the oracle configurations are  involving to this redis configurations.I mean can I neglect the definition of dataSource bean in this scenario, Because as I mentioned above I already implemented it inside the application.properties file. So then can I also neglect the implementation of  transactionManger bean too.

Comment: I mean in a nutshell what I need to know is can I neglect the implementation of transactionManger bean and dataSource bean.

Comment: yes you can ignore the implementation of PlatformTransactionManager given you have added `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` dependency. The starter JDBC will create this bean for you.

Comment: @sonous21 Thank you very much for your commitment. Finally I need to clarify when it comes to implementing the support of Transactional annotation to handle the  transactions in Redis , according to my application what I need to do is implementing the above source code by neglecting the  transactionManger bean and dataSource bean.I am I correct ?

Comment: It seems you're mixing transaction support in RDBMS and Redis. Redis transaction is different, NoSQL db like Redis has the support of transaction for a different purpose.

Comment: @sonous21 I didn't get your point. According to my findings Redis also have a mechanism to handle transactions as same as the RDBMS. Please refer the link which is at the end of my post .But the problem is same as in RDBMS developer need to handle that manually. So to avoid that overhead we can use Transactional annotation just like we are using it with our normal databases to handle transactions. But according to my findings to enable Transactional annotation support we have to do some configurations. My post is all about that. So what I am asking is that the case , is my approach correct ?